# Android - Error while passing data into DatabaseHandler class

Tags: java, android

So, I have an activity that (on a button click) will send a String, double, double to a `DatabaseHandler` class which will save it into the database. When I use `db.addLocation(new Location(name, lat, lng));` I get the error

`The addLocation(com.example.stands.Location) in the type`DatabaseHandler`is not applicable for the arguments android.location.Location`

**Activity.java:**

```
package com.example.stands;

import com.example.stands.DatabaseHandler;

public class AddLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private Button saveLocation;
    DatabaseHandler db;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_location);
        saveLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveLocation);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager)     getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        final Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        saveLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insert("McDonalds",129.092093. 103.39284);
            }
        });
    }

    public void insert(String name, double lat, double lng) {
        db.addLocation(new Location(name, lat, lng));
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java:**

```
package com.example.stands;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locationsManager";

    // Locations table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";

    // Locations Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_LONG = "long";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOCATIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LONG + " DOUBLE," 
                + KEY_LAT + " DOUBLE" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOCATIONS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new location
    void addLocation(Location location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, location.getName()); // location Name
        values.put(KEY_LONG, location.getLongitude()); // location Latitude
        values.put(KEY_LAT, location.getLatitude());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single location
    Location getLocation(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOCATIONS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_LONG }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Location location = new Location(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
        // return location
        return location;
    }

    // Getting All locations
    public List<Location> getAllLocations() {
        List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Location location = new Location();
                location.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                location.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
                location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
                // Adding location to list
                locationList.add(location);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return location list
        return locationList;
    }

    // Updating single location
    public int updateLocation(Location location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, location.getName());
        values.put(KEY_LONG, location.getLongitude());
        values.put(KEY_LAT, location.getLatitude());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_LOCATIONS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(location.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single location
    public void deleteLocation(Location location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_LOCATIONS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(location.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting location Count
    public int getLocationCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

**Location.java:**

```
public class Location {

    // private variables
    int id;
    String name;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    // Empty constructor
    public Location() {
    }

    // constructor
    public Location(int id, String name, double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    // constructor
    public Location(String name, double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?

EDIT: I have used the `DatabaseHandler` class before in another activity and it worked fine.

Comment: You have two Location classes, in different packages

Comment: What @PabloLozano said is correct. Check your imports -- there's android.location.location import in your code.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm confused as to WHAT android.location.location is. Explain? I must have clicked "import" by accident at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `com.example.stands.Location(the class that you created)` in `DatabaseHandler` while in your activity you are using `android.location.Location` which is giving you this error.

Change

```
db.addLocation(new Location(name, lat, lng));
```

to

```
db.addLocation(new com.example.stands.Location(name, lat, lng));
```

Comment: Can anyone please suggest how this answer can be improved?

Comment: It can't be. it worked and was straight to the point. Will accept when I'm able to. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in my opinion the class used in the Activity does not affect. The problem is DatabaseHandler is in the same package that the Location class. But I think your solution is right.

Comment: Thanks i don't know why it was downvoted i mean you can create a class like this and it works perfectly fine.